# Tex to Word Pipeline With Reference File

Tags: latex, pandoc, bibtex, pdftotext, overleaf

I would like to convert my overleaf template to a word document for my collaborators to edit directly outside of Overleaf. I am aware of Pandoc to convert the text file to word

```
pandoc -o Test.docx Test.tex
```

However, my tex document uses references in .bib format (and a separate file) and those are lost in the conversion.

My File Structure:

```
- Project
|
|-- Test.tex
|-- References.bib
|-- Test.pdf
```

Test.pdf does include the references, however is there an option to include references in pandoc or does anyone have a pdf to word converted they recommend that is open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research concerning this topic (LaTeX to Word conversion) recently. It seems you can generate the pdf file and then directly open it in Word. The only problem is that hyperlinks and cross-references will be lost. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc).

Although you asked for an open source option, I suppose you (or your collaborators) have access to Word, since you want to convert to it.

It is also not clear if you need the hyperlinks to be preserved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think this will do for my needs, thanks @viking

Comment: I'm glad to help.